# Why Telethon cleint.get_entity(id) print error "missing argument: 'entity'"?

Tags: python, telethon

I try get chat through ID in that code, like in [api](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/entities.html#getting-entities):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import secret
client = TelegramClient('opentfd_session', secret.api_id, secret.api_hash).start()
chat_admin = TelegramClient.get_entity(secret.chat_id)
```

I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\krutm\Documents\opentfd\opentfd.py", line 23, in <module>
    chat_admin = TelegramClient.get_entity(secret.chat_id)
  File "C:\Users\krutm\Documents\opentfd\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\sync.py", line 34, in syncified
    coro = method(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get_entity() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entity'
```

I don't understand what entity, if I need get entity from this method. What should I do?

Comment: Shouldnt it be `chat_admin = client.get_entity(secret.chat_id)`

Comment: I tried through link and it get the same mistake, other way: `chat_admin = TelegramClient.get_entity('telegram.me/joinchat/HmiuoBdFqEGHIVkaeljI3A')`
It will the same mistake

Comment: The package `TelegramClient` doesnt have a method called `get_entity`. you need to call this method on the `client` object your created `client.get_entity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading telethon doc would help you much more. You don't have basic knowledge about client even. Btw the method is used as follows:

```
await client.get_entity(id/username/link)
```

Comment: From doc:
`# Other kind of entities.
channel = await client.get_entity('telegram.me/joinchat/AAAAAEkk2WdoDrB4-Q8-gg')`
I tried through link and it get the same mistake
`chat_admin = TelegramClient.get_entity('telegram.me/joinchat/xxxx')`

Comment: @krutmaster you need to use the client object you created not the telegramClient package

Comment: @krutmaster try with client object and it will work. The example with private link is as follows : await client.get_entity(private link). You can also print the code to see its all entities